# Downloading file without direct link through C# Webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to download a file but the problem is that the URL is not a direct link to the zip file, and my code gives me useless error.

This is the code:

```
var zipFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(directory.FullName, "temp.zip"));
var progressInfo =
    new ProgressBarInfo(
        $"{DateTime.Now:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff}\t[PROGRESS] Download IP2Location database");
UiManager.UiImplementation.ShowProgressBar(progressInfo);
try
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient { Proxy = null })
    {
        var url = $"https://www.ip2location.com/download/?token={downloadToken}&file={DatabaseProduct}";
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged +=
            (sender, args) =>
                progressInfo.ReportProgress(args.ProgressPercentage / 100d);
        using (var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        {
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, args) => autoResetEvent.Set();
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), zipFile.FullName);
            autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    progressInfo.Close();
}
```

If I change the URL variable to a direct link eg: https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin
then the code works fine

If I visit this URL: https://www.ip2location.com/download/?token=REDACTED&file=DB11LITE
it will directly download a file named IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB11.CSV.ZIP

This is the response header when I visit the URL in my browser

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 13 Dec 2021 23:22:15 GMT
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Length: 48726637
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: private
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="IP2LOCATION-LITE-DB11.CSV.ZIP"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Security-Policy: default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';frame-ancestors 'self';
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to note that the `Webclient` class uses the RETR command to download an FTP resource. For an HTTP resource, the GET method is used. That means if you provide a URL that doesn't contains the correct parameters to a downloadable file, you gonna end up with some exceptions that are not handled because `Webclient` was replaced with `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`, that I recommend you use instead.

Below you can see a exemple of how the `Webclient` works, on your case you are getting "useless error" because you are on a async method. I would suggest to use the normal method like below to debug and get the correct exception.

```
public void downloadProgrambyURL(string url, string filename)
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    var pathVariable = "%USERPROFILE%\\Downloads\\" + filename;
                    var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(pathVariable);
                    client.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
                }
            }
```

Also, I'll let [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?view=net-6.0) link for your reference.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help.
I could reproduce the error thx to the "DownloadFile" method.
The issue was SSL/TLS secure channel error.